# How to prove that these two matrices have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help at the following exercise:

"Prove that if $ A,B \in M_{n \times n} ( \mathbb{R})$, then the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues."

Could you give some hint?

I thought that I could use the fact that:

If A and B are two square n×n matrices then characteristic polynomials of AB and BA coincide.

So $det(AB- λ I)=det(BA- λ I).$ How could I continue? Or is this way wrong?

Comment: [Here's one way to approach the problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712190/f-g-in-textend-v-share-the-same-eigenvalues-for-f-circ-g-and-g-circ/712205#712205)

Comment: When you say that you can use the fact that the characteristic polynomials of AB and BA coincide, do you mean that you have already proven/seen this fact?

Comment: So, to summarize the comments so far, you can't just say that those two determinants (or characteristic polynomials) will be the same straight-off.  Check the two linked problems, and see if you can understand any of those approaches.  If not, update this question or make a new question to ask about the specifics of one of those proofs that you don't understand.

Comment: The first suggested duplicate deals with potentially non-square matrices (which makes this more complicated). The second suggested duplicate is handled abstractly in such a way the problem looks more difficult. In fact, the abstract version could be handled more efficiently/cleanly by using determinants as suggested by the OP.

Comment: @BillCook notice in the case that $A$ is invertible, we have $AB = A(BA)A^{-1}$, which I think is easier than dealing with determinants.